# What is this mountain bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I saw this bike on some Instagram account I follow. Can someone tell me the name of it because I can’t seem to find it anywhere?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44igO.jpg)

Comment: I would guess that it's a [Kona Stinky](http://www.konaworld.com/stinky_24.cfm).  There are 24 and 26-inch versions.

Comment: Generally the names going down the tubes are manufacturer and/or model names. I would concur with @DanielRHicks, this is a Kona Stinky.

Comment: That was easy! Makes a nice change from the usual unidentifiable generic BMX frames.

Comment: @DanielRHicks that's totally an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As people already mentioned in the comments, it's old good Kona Stinky. For me this is a symbolic bike, Paul Bassagotia, one of the pioneers of the freeride scene, used to ride on it before moving to Scott. You can find more detail on specs it had here: http://www.konabikeworld.com/08_stinky_w.htm

And here we can see Kona's older catalogue, including older Stinkies http://www.konabikeworld.com/tech/catalog/catalog_2k4.htm